# How to invoke linux ssh from the custom shell?

Tags: c, linux, ssh, pipe, ipc

I have a custom shell, which runs in one process. I want to use the inbuilt ssh available in Linux. I want to redirect the user I/O from the custom CLI to the actual linux shell. 
Here is what I have done to do ssh:

```
INT4 do_ssh(tCliHandle CliHandle, CHR1  *destIp)
{
    FILE *writePipe = NULL;
    char readbuff[1024];
    char cmd[1024];

    memset(cmd,'\0',sizeof(cmd));

    sprintf(cmd,"/usr/bin/ssh %s",destIp);

    printf("cmd = %s\r\n",cmd);

    writePipe = popen(cmd,"w");

    if(writePipe == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    while( fgets(readbuff,sizeof(readbuff) - 1, writePipe) != NULL)
    {
        CliPrintf(CliHandle,"%s\r\n", readbuff);
        //printf("%s",readbuff);
    }

    printf("Closing writePipe\r\n");
    pclose(writePipe);


    return 0;
}
```

The problem, which I see is that after doing ssh I can't see the session anymore.

Here is the output:

```
cust# ssh 192.168.10.42
cmd = /usr/bin/ssh 192.168.10.42
Closing writePipe
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Could not create directory '/root/.ssh'.
root@192.168.10.42's password: 
ssh 192.168.10.42
```

My expectation is to keep the session alive and let the user keep sending the command from the terminal and it should get printed on the terminal.
But, I see that after ssh the session is closed. I want to keep it open.
I want to close only when the window is closed or exit is passed. 
What I should do? Any hints will be helpful.

Comment: SSH is just a regular command; run it like any other. (Also, it's not "built in", any more than `grep` or `find`.)

Comment: As the output says ssh can't read the password because its stdin doesn't have peeudoterminal c capabilities. Thus, the session can't be authenticated and it's closed preliminary

Comment: You may find more *nix experts on one of the other SE sites targeted to *nix. That said, a look at the ssh manual makes me believe that one of the options may help (-f? -T?).

Comment: Do you use keys or password, or both for ssh's authentification?

Comment: For any automation, you'll want to set up passwordless SSH.